# Im trying consuming a soap service and response is null

Tags: java, spring, soap

I am trying to consume a soap service with java and spring also maven-jaxb2-plugin.

this is my controller

```
import java.sql.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.consumingwebservice.wsdl.TransferenciaDocumentos;
import com.example.consumingwebservice.wsdl.TransferenciaDocumentosRequest;
import com.example.consumingwebservice.wsdl.TransferenciaDocumentosResponse;

import client.TransferenciaDocumentosClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class AzurianWsApplication {
    
    @Autowired
    private TransferenciaDocumentosClient client;
    
    @GetMapping("/getDocumentos")
    public TransferenciaDocumentosResponse invokeDocumentosResponse () {
    
         TransferenciaDocumentos documentos = new TransferenciaDocumentos();
         TransferenciaDocumentosRequest request = new TransferenciaDocumentosRequest();
        
         request.setFechaDesde(Date.valueOf("2021-10-01"));
         request.setFechaDesde(Date.valueOf("2021-12-31"));
         request.setNroResolucion(0);
         request.setRutEmpresa(7656066);
         request.setWsApiKey("60fa6eb48c91c4e704a4d9c22c19ee");
         documentos.setRequest(request);
    
        
        return client.transferenciaDocumentosResponse(documentos);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AzurianWsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

when I make the request with the sample data it returns null, instead if I do the same test in SoapUi this one does return data,
I leave the client class below.

```
package cl.nobelti.grupogtd.azuriantoax.client;

import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;

import com.example.consumingwebservice.wsdl.TransferenciaDocumentos;
import com.example.consumingwebservice.wsdl.TransferenciaDocumentosResponse;

public class TransferenciaDocumentosClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport{
    
    public TransferenciaDocumentosResponse transferenciaDocumentosResponse(TransferenciaDocumentos request) {
                
        TransferenciaDocumentosResponse response = (TransferenciaDocumentosResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
            .marshalSendAndReceive("http://soa.group.com:7503/serviciorecepcion?wsdl", request);
        
        return response;
    }
}
```

I am using the spring guide to do this, I attach it in case you want to see it:

> https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

my response looks something like this:

```
    "transferenciaDocumentosReturn": {
        "codigoRespuesta": null,
        "descripcion": null,
        "documentos": null
    }
}
```

I think the request is not coming but it prints it and it really is there, please help!